# Folder created in terminal does not give access to control panel user

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, litespeed, cyberpanel

I have made a script which creates a folder (`website`) in the public path of a website that belongs to a website control panel (`CyberPanel`):

```
mkdir /home/example.com/website/
```

But this command does not give enough permissions to the panel user to create or edit files inside it, the permissions are:

```
ls -la /home/example.com/website/

total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root    4096 Dec 14 11:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 softs4939 nogroup 4096 Dec 14 11:49 ..
```

when I create a folder in the panel, I get the permissions:

```
ls -la /home/example.com/website/

total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 softs4939 softs4939 4096 Dec 14 11:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 softs4939 nogroup   4096 Dec 14 11:49 ..
```

which lets the panel user to edit anything in it.

How do I make the folder and all its file inside it (made in terminal) to be editable by panel user?

Comment: Have you installed cPanel to your server?

Comment: I am using CyberPanel with OpenLightSpeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three options:

1. Run the command as the target user, not as root.

   ```
   sudo -u softs4939 mkdir /home/example.com/website/
   ```
2. run chown afterwards

   ```
   mkdir /home/example.com/website/
   chown softs4939:softs4939 /home/example.com/website/
   ```
3. use `install`

   ```
   install -o softs4939 -g softs4939 -d /home/example.com/website/
   ```

Personally, I prefer option 3 in such scripts.